# Javascript: Recursively remove select keys

Tags: javascript

I have a huge Javascript array (20MB).
The following code doesn't work, I need to recursively search the big array, and delete any entrie where the array key matching an item in the removal list.

```
let largeArray = //Call's to API.
smallArray = clean(largeArray);
let removal = ["geocoded_waypoints", "request", "routes"];
console.log("Routes: " + smallArray);


function clean(obj) {
    // For each item in the multidomensional array.
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {

        // For each item in the removal array. Check it if needs to be removed.
        let removeThis = false;
        removal.every((element) => {
            if (key === element) {
                removeThis = true;
            }
        });

        // Check if the array is a value, or an array. loop recursively as required.
        if (removeThis === false) {
            if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
                // Item needs to be kept, if it's an array, recurse.
                obj[key] = clean(obj[key]);
            }
        } else {
            console.log("Removing: Key: " + key + ", Value: " + obj[key]);
            delete obj[key];
        }
    });

    return obj;
}
```

Comment: try using the Array filter function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: In addition to my answer, I'd like to provide you with some quick feedback: in the future, please provide example input data (preferably the smallest example you can create), the resulting output, and the expected output. While I was able to determine the issue through experimentation, it will generally help us solve your problem if we know what your code should be doing and what it's actually doing, which will likewise lead to faster, more helpful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using the `every()` method, which is designed to test if all elements of an array pass a particular condition. Its internal implementation is such that if any iteration on the array returns a non-truthy value, then it will simply stop executing--after all, if we encounter one element that doesn't match the condition, then that means it's not true that every element matches the condition, so checking the remaining elements is wasted effort!

So if, for example, we have the key `"request"`, the `every()` method will first check `"geocoded_waypoints"` and your callback function does not return a `true` value, so the method determines that it should stop running and will not attempt the `"request"` value next. You can see this by doing the following:

```
let largeArray = //Call's to API.
smallArray = clean(largeArray);
let removal = ["geocoded_waypoints", "request", "routes"];
console.log("Routes: " + smallArray);

function clean(obj) {
    // For each item in the multidomensional array.
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {

        // For each item in the removal array. Check it if needs to be removed.
        let removeThis = false;
        removal.every((element) => {
            console.log('Comparing key to "' + element + '".');
            if (key === element) {
                removeThis = true;
            }
        });

        // Check if the array is a value, or an array. loop recursively as required.
        if (removeThis === false) {
            if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
                // Item needs to be kept, if it's an array, recurse.
                obj[key] = clean(obj[key]);
            }
        } else {
            console.log("Removing: Key: " + key + ", Value: " + obj[key]);
            delete obj[key];
        }
    });

    return obj;
}
```

If you run this function, you will see that it only ever checks `"geocoded_waypoints"`, never checking `"request"` or `"routes"`.

In other words, you're using the wrong tool for the job.

Instead of using the `every()` method, use the `includes()` method to check if the array of elements we want to remove contains the key we're currently checking:

```
let largeArray = //Call's to API.
smallArray = clean(largeArray);
let removal = ["geocoded_waypoints", "request", "routes"];
console.log("Routes: " + smallArray);


function clean(obj) {
    // For each item in the multidomensional array.
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {

        // Check if this key is in the array of keys that should be removed.
        let removeThis = removal.includes(key);

        // Check if the array is a value, or an array. loop recursively as required.
        if (removeThis === false) {
            if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
                // Item needs to be kept, if it's an array, recurse.
                obj[key] = clean(obj[key]);
            }
        } else {
            console.log("Removing: Key: " + key + ", Value: " + obj[key]);
            delete obj[key];
        }
    });

    return obj;
}
```

Comment: this worked perfectly, greatly appreciated.

Comment: @JamesHudson No problem! Please remember to also accept the answer to indicate to other users that your problem has been solved :)